# List of files in a specific directory and size - linux command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ls

How could I get the list of files and size in a specific directory and store the result in a text file.

For example:

For directory /some/directory I would like a file listing all the files contained in that directory like this:

```
fileA sizeofA dateA
fileB sizeofB dateB
fileC sizeofC dateC
fileD sizeofD dateD
```

Answer (score 2):

Test this using `stat` :

```
cd /some/directory
stat -c '%n %B %y' *
```

See

```
man 1 stat
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stat` command:

```
stat -c '%n %s %y' *
```